# Understanding decorators python

Tags: python, class, decorator

I am trying to understand the concept of `decorators` in python and I think I understand the intuition. However, I'm looking at a piece of code which is a bit confusing in its implementation. The use of `decorator @property` in the code snip below is confusing to me since I don't see any reference to the actual definition of the decorator function `@property` in the code and as should be done according to this tutorial: 
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_decorators.php

```
Class Config:
    def __init__(self, feature_dim, size):
       self._feature_dim = feature_dim
       self.size = size

    @property
    def feature_dim(self):
        return self._feature_dim
    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size


Class Model:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self._config = config


#call for the classes "config" and "model" below
    config = Config(feature_dim=10, size=100)
    model = Model(config)
```

Comment: @property is a built-in decorator [mor info](https://www.journaldev.com/14893/python-property-decorator)

Comment: So @property is a special type of decorator for class. These decorators are built-into python and aren't the custom decorators that the tutorial shows you

Comment: This isn't related to ``property`` being a decorator at all (decorators are syntax, not types), but Python's scoping rules that always has all members of the ``builtins`` module visible by default.